# I cant figure it out something on a c++ application

Tags: c++, onkeypress

So i'm making a c++ application to solve some exercises.

```
int i=1;
cout << "How many times :";
cin >> n;
while (n>0)
{
    cout << "Input F" << i << ":";
    if (cin >> a[i] && cin >> sign&& cin>>b)
    {
                switch (sign)
                {
                case'$': a[i] = a[i] * (sqrt(b));
                    break;
                case'^': a[i] = pow(a[i], b);
                    break;
                case'/':a[i] = a[i] / b;
                    break;
                default: cout << "\n Wrong sign";
                    break;
                }
    }
    else
        a[i]=a[i];
i++;
n--;
}
```

In some cases i dont need the sing or b variabels... and the application doesent allow me to quit the if when i press Enter .

For example : i have to input F1: 8sqrt(2) and i type 8$2 then F2: just 8 then i press Enter,but the application keep asking for values.

Ok, so now to make it work i need to type the sign twice in a row...

```
while (n>0)
{
    cout << "Input F" << i << ":";
    cin >> a[i];
    if (cin.get() == '\n')
        a[i] = a[i];
    else {
        cin >> sign;
        if (sign)
            cin >> b;
        switch (sign)
        {
        case'$':
            a[i] = a[i] * (sqrt(b));
            break;
        case'^': a[i] = pow(a[i], b);
            break;
        case'/':a[i] = a[i] / b;
            break;
        default: cout << "\n Wrong sing;
            break;
        }
    }
i++;
n--;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would not put cin in an IF statement. Try putting your cin's above the IF, then test it agin.

Comment: Yea,but how do i cin the sign only when it's typed?

Comment: Please improve the title of the question. As written a future visitor who may have the same problem will not be able to find it because the title is too vague.

Comment: @Developer I don't see any harm in that OP has done with the `if`. `>>` returns a reference to the `istream` and the `if` will use [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to test the returned `istream` for failure. The logic of how to catch the sign may be wrong, but otherwise this is a classic example of how to do a test of chained reads right.

Comment: This is true, but it would help to make the code more readable.

Comment: More readable would look like `if (cin >> a[i] >> sign >> b)`. This takes full advantage of `iostream`'s lazy attitude toward error reporting and only performs one validity test at the end. Either all values are read or boom. Fail. Doesn't do what OP needs to do, unfortunately.

Comment: Now it work's somehow but with double sign...

Comment: You're walking in the wrong direction here. See what R Sahu did with the getline function in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> In some cases i dont need the sing or b variabels... and the application doesent allow me to quit the if when i press Enter .

That's because the program is waiting for you to enter all the values needed for

```
if (cin >> a[i] && cin >> sign&& cin>>b)
```

You can get out of that statement by entering all the necessary input or by entering an EOF (entering an EOF is platform specific).

You will be better off by reading the input line by line and processing each line independently using a `std::istringstream`.

```
while (n>0)
{
   std::string line;
   cout << "Input F" << i << ":";
   if ( ! getline(cin, line) )
   {
      // Error reading the next line.
      break;
   }

   // Now extract the data from the line using a istringstream.
   std::istringstream str(line);
   if (str >> a[i] && str >> sign && str >> b)
   {
      switch (sign)
      {
         case'$': a[i] = a[i] * (sqrt(b));
                  break;
         case'^': a[i] = pow(a[i], b);
                  break;
         case'/': a[i] = a[i] / b;
                  break;
         default: cout << "\n Wrong sign";
                  break;
       }
    }
    else
       a[i]=a[i];
    i++;
    n--;
}
```

Comment: You have fallen prey to a typo that has since been corrected.